# Как посмотреть схему amd зависимостей?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

**Дано:** большой легаси проект, организованный как amd модули, которые грузятся через requirejs.
Какие-то куски запрашиваются он-деманд изнутри модулей через вызов require.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли готовый инструмент, или какой-то несложный (я готов потратить пару часов, но не пару дней на написание своего инструмента) способ построить граф зависимостей этого проекта?

То есть я говорю тулзе папку или entry point проекта, и она мне показывает в каком-то человекоориентированном виде что от чего зависит, учитывая при этом возможные require коллы изнутри define модулей.

UPD: Прикрутил [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge). Инструмент рабочий, но требует многочисленных танцев с бубном (впрочем это чаще всего связано с используемой библиотекой graphviz, а с недостатками самого madge). Буду благодарен советам других инструментов.

Comment: Про инструменты не слышал, но возможно, как отправная точка, вам поможет **requirejs.s.contexts**, в частности **defined**

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, я думал над тем, чтобы выдрать дерево прям из requirejs, но в проекте прилично асинхронных require коллов (роутинг через них), а про них requirejs.s.context ничего не знает пока они не выполнятся. То есть  нужен именно статический анализ какой-то

Comment: @ru_volt, а если взять и построить AST по JS коду и аккуратненько обойти его вытаскивая нужные вызовы? Понимаю, что предложение бредовое и требует много работы, но вдруг окажется полезным

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну я предполагаю что тулза это делать и должна. Я потому и написал что не готов потратить пару дней) Потому что ща как нюансы повсплывают, в результате пару дней и получится. Кто-то же ну точно такую задачу до меня решал. Впрочем я почти уже разрулил madge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из альтернатив madge'у - [dependo](https://github.com/auchenberg/dependo). (см. также [grunt-dependo](https://github.com/auchenberg/grunt-dependo)). Он позволяет генерировать HTML report типа [этого](http://auchenberg.github.io/dependo/example/), где используется [d3js](http://d3js.org/) для визуализации.

Comment: а сами Вы его пробовали?

Comment: Чего я спрашиваю - я его смотрел уже наигравшись с madge, поэтому бросил на первом "что-то пошло не так"

Comment: @ru_volt: У меня никогда не возикало практических проблемм с AMD dependencies, но если и нужно, то React modules (.jsx), что несколько иная задача. В этом случае babelify, к примеру, разрешает все зависимости сам и объединяет все в один модуль во время сборки. Если Вам интересно, то я находил еще [node-dependency-tree](https://github.com/mrjoelkemp/node-dependency-tree), но сам с ним не работал.

Comment: щас я поясню "продуктовую" проблему которая это вызвала. Есть старое большое легаси SPA. Там была самописная модульная система, зависимости через моудлями фактически почти не были описаны. В один прекрасный момент систему было решено бесжалостно этот проект отрефакторить. Самописные модули я выпилил, заменил на amd модули и require. И я хочу посмотреть зависимости между модулями, чтобы выбрать цель для дальнейшего рефакторинга.

Comment: Ладно, в общем я кое-как прикрутил madge и заодно нашел в какой опенсорс проект я хочу поконтрибьютить.

Comment: Благодарю, депендо работает норм, (и в некоторых местах лучше чем madge) но тоже оч сырой

Comment: @ru_volt: Пожалуйста! А какой проэкт *Вы* публикуете на GitHub? Я, например, https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid. Мне знакомо, сколько труда это требует. Другие могут пользоваться результатами работы бесплатно. Если Вы видите, как улучшить существующий Open Source проэкт, то нужно **публиковать pull request со своими предложениями**, а не просто писать, что работа дугих "сырая".

Comment: Сырой - это констатация факта, а не предъява. И я не вижу, как мой факт участия/неучастия в опенсорсе может это изменить. Я-то как раз решился в один из этих проектов на выходных поконтрибьютить, но такие посты как ваш, желания не прибавляют, честно.